# Need help interpreting a question

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $\Bbb P_n$ of all polynomials of degree at most $n$ for some $n \geq 2$

Determine whether or not the set of all polynomials $p$ in $\Bbb P_n$ so that $p(0)=0$ is a subspace of $\Bbb P_n$

I think its simply asking me if $p(0)=0$ is an subspace of $\Bbb P_n$, but i feel that its obvious that it is and not confident if i interpreted this question correctly. Am i correct? or what is this the correct interpretation of this question.

Comment: You haven't named the collection.  Let $P = \{p \in \Bbb{P}_n \mid p(0) = 0\}$.  Is $0 \in P$?  Now, let $p,q \in P$.  Is $p+q \in P$?  Are scalar multiples of $p$ in $P$?  You have a list of properties of a vector (sub-)space, so go through and check each of them...

Comment: The question is about the subset of all polynomials satisfying the condition $p(0)=0$ being or not a vector subspace

Comment: The map $T\colon \mathbb P_n\to P$, defined by $T(p)(x) = p(x)-p(0)$ is linear and obviously $T(\mathbb P_n)=P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set the question is asking you to consider is the set of all polynomials $p \in \mathbb{P}_n$ that satisfy the condition $p(0) = 0$. Let's call that set $\mathcal{P}$.

To make it clearer, look at some examples of polynomials in $\mathbb{P}_n$ (let's let $n = 2$ for now) and consider whether they're elements of $\mathcal{P}$:

| $p(x)$ | $p(0)$ | In $\mathcal{P}$? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $x$ | $0$ | Yes |
| $2x + 1$ | $1$ | No |
| $3$ | $3$ | No |
| $7x^2 - 3x + 4$ | $4$ | No |
| $-3x^2 + 20x$ | $0$ | Yes |

So, the question asks - we already know that $\mathbb{P}_n$ is a vector space under polynomial addition and scalar multiplication. So, is $\mathcal{P}$ a subspace of it? You should have a standard set of rules to check to prove whether or not it is, so can you apply them?